# Distinguishing between user events vs model changes in ionic <ion-toggle>

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How do I distinguish between change events triggered by the user interacting with an ion-toggle vs events triggered programmatically by model changes in my component?

```
<ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="on" (ionChange)="state_toggled()"></ion-toggle>
```

Comment: you can use `ngModelChange`

Comment: can you provide example of what do you mean? like in your question "on" has 2-way binding via ngModel so user can change it (from interaction with template) and data is bound to value of "on". Do you expect ionChange to emit differentiated events the moment "on" changes by user vs by some other method?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes, that's what I expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-toggle [ngModel]="on" (ngModelChange)="userTriggered()"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
```

This way if some method would modify "on" value - userTriggered() method won't be called but toggle's state will get updated.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ci2mdm